# How to edit a Unix file to insert a few lines after 2 specific pattern matches

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with content like below. I want to edit the file so that whenever in the file the LTPGY pattern is seen then after line "set t  table new $m table]", insert a new line with content "FOUND".

The input file is as follows :-

```
  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] LTPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]



  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] STPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]


  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] LTPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]



  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] STPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]
```

I want the output to be like :-

```
  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] LTPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  FOUND
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]



  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] STPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]


  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] LTPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  FOUND
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]



  set ra [ 1 22 3 ] STPGY
  set a 0
  set a1 1

  set t [ table new $m table]
  set a [  $t process_axis]
  set a [  $t voltage_axis]
```

Comment: this is a bit broad. Could you indicate how exactly the output file should look like? also, it would be good to share your attempts

Answer (score 1):

Works with gawk, untested on other awks:

```
gawk '
    /set ra / {found = /LTPGY/}
    1;
    index($0, "set t [ table new $m table]") && found {print "FOUND"}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/LTPGY/{:a;n;/set t \[ table new $m table\]/!ba;p;s/\S.*/FOUND/}' file
```

Focus in on the lines following `LTPGY` and on finding the required string, print it then replace all but the leading spaces with the required string `FOUND`.